# Rolling sum reset based on conditions using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Using `tidyverse`/`dplyr` commands, I'd like to create several columns
1)  A column `count` that does a rolling count of the number of **unique** individuals until **at least** 30 unique individuals have been chosen **and** `lastObsG==1` and `lastObsGE==1` (i.e. the end of a gene has been reached). The count should reset once `count` exceeds around 30 individuals.
2) A column `group` that indicates the group number of each set of ~30 individuals.

The individuals are ordered by the location of their mutation.

As a minimum working example, my dataset and the code to create variables `lastObsG` and `lastObsGE` are provided below. I've also included the output for the first 40 lines, which includes the extra columns and what values should appear in them.

**EDIT**
Per @Alexis's comment, I meant to say that each group should contain at least 30 individuals, as long as the last observation satisfies `lastObsG==1` and `lastObsGE==1`. As seen in the sample output, there are four duplicated individuals in group 1, so a total of 37 observations from 33 unique individuals should be grouped.

---

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(gene) %>%
  mutate(lastObsFlagG = as.integer(row_number() == n())) %>%
  group_by(gene,exon) %>%
  mutate(lastObsFlagGE = as.integer(row_number() == n())) %>%
  data.frame()
```

---

**Sample Output**

```
             ID    gene exon mutation lastObsFlagG lastObsFlagGE count group
1  TCGA-AN-A046   OR4F5   E1    69767            1             1     1     1
2  TCGA-A2-A0CP  SAMD11   E2   925952            1             1     2     1
3  TCGA-A8-A08H   NOC2L   E5   956126            0             1     3     1
4  TCGA-GM-A2DM   NOC2L   E4   956911            0             0     4     1
5  TCGA-GM-A2DM   NOC2L   E4   956912            1             1     4     1
6  TCGA-D8-A1XM  KLHL17   E3   961658            0             1     5     1
7  TCGA-BH-A18G  KLHL17   E5   962441            0             1     6     1
8  TCGA-3C-AALI  KLHL17   E8   963353            0             1     7     1
9  TCGA-AC-A62Y  KLHL17   E9   964004            1             1     8     1
10 TCGA-AR-A2LE PLEKHN1   E1   966556            0             1     9     1
11 TCGA-E2-A14N PLEKHN1   E5   970728            0             1    10     1
12 TCGA-AO-A0J4 PLEKHN1  E12   973506            1             1    11     1
13 TCGA-D8-A1J9    HES4   E3   999551            1             1    12     1
14 TCGA-EW-A1PH   ISG15   E2  1014276            1             1    13     1
15 TCGA-A2-A0T0    AGRN   E2  1022338            0             1    14     1
16 TCGA-GM-A2DD    AGRN   E3  1035303            0             1    15     1
17 TCGA-5L-AAT1    AGRN   E4  1040690            0             1    16     1
18 TCGA-OL-A5RW    AGRN   E8  1043314            0             1    17     1
19 TCGA-D8-A27M    AGRN  E25  1049355            0             1    18     1
20 TCGA-AR-A1AI    AGRN  E29  1050430            0             1    19     1
21 TCGA-5L-AAT0    AGRN  E36  1055374            0             0    20     1
22 TCGA-5L-AAT0    AGRN  E36  1055376            0             0    20     1
23 TCGA-C8-A8HP    AGRN  E36  1055442            1             1    21     1
24 TCGA-A7-A4SD  TTLL10  E13  1184971            1             1    22     1
25 TCGA-BH-A1F0    SDF4   E4  1223283            0             0    23     1
26 TCGA-AO-A128    SDF4   E4  1223330            0             1    24     1
27 TCGA-E9-A1R0    SDF4   E2  1228592            1             1    25     1
28 TCGA-A2-A04P  UBE2J2   E7  1255246            0             0    26     1
29 TCGA-C8-A274  UBE2J2   E7  1255342            1             1    27     1
30 TCGA-5L-AAT1  SCNN1D   E1  1281422            0             1    27     1
31 TCGA-AO-A128  SCNN1D   E6  1287116            0             1    27     1
32 TCGA-E2-A15R  SCNN1D   E7  1287596            0             1    28     1
33 TCGA-AC-A62V  SCNN1D  E11  1290543            1             1    29     1
34 TCGA-BH-A18V   ACAP3  E22  1294187            0             1    30     1
35 TCGA-A7-A6VX   ACAP3   E6  1300640            0             1    31     1
36 TCGA-GM-A2DB   ACAP3   E3  1303170            0             0    32     1
37 TCGA-EW-A1IY   ACAP3   E3  1303176            1             1    33    1
38 TCGA-D8-A1XQ  CPSF3L   E9  1313879            0             0     5     2
39 TCGA-5L-AAT1  CPSF3L   E9  1313888            0             1     6     2
40 TCGA-C8-A26Y  CPSF3L   E7  1314919            0             1     7     2
```

---

**Dataset**

```
"ID"    "gene"  "exon"  "mutation"
"TCGA-AN-A046"  "OR4F5" "E1"    69767
"TCGA-A2-A0CP"  "SAMD11"    "E2"    925952
"TCGA-A8-A08H"  "NOC2L" "E5"    956126
"TCGA-GM-A2DM"  "NOC2L" "E4"    956911
"TCGA-GM-A2DM"  "NOC2L" "E4"    956912
"TCGA-D8-A1XM"  "KLHL17"    "E3"    961658
"TCGA-BH-A18G"  "KLHL17"    "E5"    962441
"TCGA-3C-AALI"  "KLHL17"    "E8"    963353
"TCGA-AC-A62Y"  "KLHL17"    "E9"    964004
"TCGA-AR-A2LE"  "PLEKHN1"   "E1"    966556
"TCGA-E2-A14N"  "PLEKHN1"   "E5"    970728
"TCGA-AO-A0J4"  "PLEKHN1"   "E12"   973506
"TCGA-D8-A1J9"  "HES4"  "E3"    999551
"TCGA-EW-A1PH"  "ISG15" "E2"    1014276
"TCGA-A2-A0T0"  "AGRN"  "E2"    1022338
"TCGA-GM-A2DD"  "AGRN"  "E3"    1035303
"TCGA-5L-AAT1"  "AGRN"  "E4"    1040690
"TCGA-OL-A5RW"  "AGRN"  "E8"    1043314
"TCGA-D8-A27M"  "AGRN"  "E25"   1049355
"TCGA-AR-A1AI"  "AGRN"  "E29"   1050430
"TCGA-5L-AAT0"  "AGRN"  "E36"   1055374
"TCGA-5L-AAT0"  "AGRN"  "E36"   1055376
"TCGA-C8-A8HP"  "AGRN"  "E36"   1055442
"TCGA-A7-A4SD"  "TTLL10"    "E13"   1184971
"TCGA-BH-A1F0"  "SDF4"  "E4"    1223283
"TCGA-AO-A128"  "SDF4"  "E4"    1223330
"TCGA-E9-A1R0"  "SDF4"  "E2"    1228592
"TCGA-A2-A04P"  "UBE2J2"    "E7"    1255246
"TCGA-C8-A274"  "UBE2J2"    "E7"    1255342
"TCGA-5L-AAT1"  "SCNN1D"    "E1"    1281422
"TCGA-AO-A128"  "SCNN1D"    "E6"    1287116
"TCGA-E2-A15R"  "SCNN1D"    "E7"    1287596
"TCGA-AC-A62V"  "SCNN1D"    "E11"   1290543
"TCGA-BH-A18V"  "ACAP3" "E22"   1294187
"TCGA-A7-A6VX"  "ACAP3" "E6"    1300640
"TCGA-GM-A2DB"  "ACAP3" "E3"    1303170
"TCGA-EW-A1IY"  "ACAP3" "E3"    1303176
"TCGA-D8-A1XQ"  "CPSF3L"    "E9"    1313879
"TCGA-5L-AAT1"  "CPSF3L"    "E9"    1313888
"TCGA-C8-A26Y"  "CPSF3L"    "E7"    1314919
"TCGA-D8-A1XK"  "CPSF3L"    "E2"    1321057
"TCGA-AO-A128"  "TAS1R3"    "E2"    1331863
"TCGA-A8-A07P"  "TAS1R3"    "E6"    1334323
"TCGA-A7-A0DA"  "DVL1"  "E14"   1338066
"TCGA-C8-A8HQ"  "DVL1"  "E10"   1339589
"TCGA-BH-A18T"  "DVL1"  "E8"    1340130
"TCGA-C8-A12V"  "MXRA8" "E6"    1354445
"TCGA-C8-A3M8"  "AURKAIP1"  "E2"    1374747
"TCGA-BH-A0B6"  "CCNL2" "E11"   1387308
"TCGA-A8-A09Z"  "CCNL2" "E4"    1395413
"TCGA-AC-A23H"  "MRPL20"    "E4"    1402084
"TCGA-BH-A1FU"  "MRPL20"    "E4"    1402116
"TCGA-BH-A0W4"  "MRPL20"    "E4"    1402194
"TCGA-AR-A1AH"  "MRPL20"    "E4"    1402205
"TCGA-A8-A06Q"  "ANKRD65"   "E1"    1420868
"TCGA-AC-A8OQ"  "ATAD3C"    "E1"    1450566
"TCGA-A2-A25A"  "ATAD3C"    "E11"   1462661
"TCGA-AR-A5QQ"  "ATAD3B"    "E7"    1482563
"TCGA-AO-A1KS"  "ATAD3B"    "E12"   1487900
"TCGA-AO-A124"  "ATAD3B"    "E15"   1490662
"TCGA-A7-A56D"  "ATAD3B"    "E16"   1495857
"TCGA-D8-A27N"  "ATAD3B"    "E16"   1495961
"TCGA-AR-A2LH"  "ATAD3A"    "E5"    1518929
"TCGA-EW-A1OY"  "ATAD3A"    "E12"   1525277
"TCGA-AO-A128"  "ATAD3A"    "E16"   1533987
"TCGA-BH-A1FM"  "SSU72" "E3"    1544993
"TCGA-C8-A12Y"  "MIB2"  "E4"    1623874
"TCGA-AC-A23H"  "MIB2"  "E7"    1625321
"TCGA-B6-A0RV"  "MIB2"  "E10"   1626960
"TCGA-E2-A1LG"  "MIB2"  "E19"   1629667
"TCGA-C8-A1HI"  "SLC35E2B"  "E8"    1668398
"TCGA-A2-A0CR"  "SLC35E2B"  "E8"    1668406
"TCGA-PL-A8LZ"  "SLC35E2B"  "E7"    1669727
"TCGA-C8-A3M7"  "CDK11A"    "E17"   1703847
"TCGA-D8-A1JP"  "CDK11A"    "E17"   1703884
"TCGA-C8-A1HK"  "CDK11A"    "E17"   1703915
"TCGA-D8-A27G"  "CDK11A"    "E15"   1704265
"TCGA-5L-AAT1"  "CDK11A"    "E13"   1705003
"TCGA-D8-A1JE"  "CDK11A"    "E11"   1707419
"TCGA-BH-A18P"  "CDK11A"    "E5"    1716352
"TCGA-D8-A27G"  "CDK11A"    "E5"    1716387
"TCGA-EW-A6SD"  "CDK11A"    "E5"    1716477
"TCGA-BH-A0W4"  "CDK11A"    "E3"    1721601
"TCGA-AN-A049"  "CDK11A"    "E3"    1721603
"TCGA-D8-A1XK"  "SLC35E2"   "E3"    1739030
"TCGA-LL-A5YM"  "SLC35E2"   "E1"    1745772
"TCGA-A7-A26H"  "NADK"  "E5"    1756596
"TCGA-AO-A128"  "GNB1"  "E5"    1815804
"TCGA-A2-A3Y0"  "CALML6"    "E4"    1916819
"TCGA-AR-A0U3"  "CALML6"    "E4"    1916828
"TCGA-AR-A5QQ"  "GABRD" "E3"    2025399
"TCGA-A2-A0CP"  "PRKCZ" "E8"    2148880
"TCGA-A2-A3Y0"  "PRKCZ" "E13"   2172304
"TCGA-E2-A15E"  "PRKCZ" "E13"   2172364
"TCGA-BH-A18N"  "C1orf86"   "E2"    2194056
"TCGA-OL-A5D6"  "SKI"   "E1"    2229410
"TCGA-BH-A2L8"  "SKI"   "E3"    2303317
"TCGA-D8-A4Z1"  "SKI"   "E5"    2304504
"TCGA-BH-A0B6"  "SKI"   "E5"    2304579
"TCGA-GM-A2D9"  "MORN1" "E14"   2321445
"TCGA-AR-A0TR"  "MORN1" "E12"   2336532
"TCGA-BH-A18G"  "MORN1" "E8"    2372498
"TCGA-AN-A0FV"  "MORN1" "E8"    2372505
"TCGA-AN-A0FV"  "MORN1" "E8"    2372506
"TCGA-BH-A0HF"  "MORN1" "E8"    2372521
"TCGA-E2-A1IG"  "MORN1" "E8"    2372562
"TCGA-AQ-A04J"  "MORN1" "E7"    2374471
"TCGA-BH-A1F5"  "MORN1" "E4"    2387496
"TCGA-A8-A09Z"  "MORN1" "E3"    2388258
"TCGA-BH-A0HA"  "MORN1" "E3"    2388291
"TCGA-B6-A0IA"  "RER1"  "E2"    2397118
"TCGA-E2-A10C"  "PEX10" "E3"    2408786
"TCGA-AC-A3HN"  "PLCH2" "E1"    2476493
"TCGA-AC-A8OP"  "PLCH2" "E3"    2479760
"TCGA-A2-A0YK"  "PLCH2" "E5"    2484610
"TCGA-B6-A0IK"  "PLCH2" "E11"   2491251
"TCGA-C8-A135"  "PLCH2" "E18"   2498827
"TCGA-E2-A15E"  "PLCH2" "E19"   2499127
"TCGA-PE-A5DE"  "PLCH2" "E22"   2504427
"TCGA-LD-A74U"  "PANK4" "E16"   2510680
"TCGA-S3-AA10"  "PANK4" "E15"   2511386
"TCGA-C8-A1HM"  "PANK4" "E10"   2515609
"TCGA-AC-A23H"  "PANK4" "E7"    2519284
"TCGA-BH-A18N"  "PANK4" "E4"    2520820
"TCGA-BH-A0HF"  "PANK4" "E4"    2520821
"TCGA-BH-A0HF"  "PANK4" "E3"    2521173
"TCGA-5L-AAT1"  "PANK4" "E3"    2521297
"TCGA-B6-A0RN"  "PANK4" "E2"    2521747
"TCGA-5L-AAT1"  "PANK4" "E1"    2526579
"TCGA-C8-A12V"  "TNFRSF14"  "E3"    2558349
"TCGA-OL-A66P"  "TNFRSF14"  "E6"    2561704
"TCGA-A2-A25F"  "TNFRSF14"  "E6"    2561714
"TCGA-AC-A23H"  "TNFRSF14"  "E8"    2563296
"TCGA-A7-A6VV"  "MMEL1" "E20"   2592868
"TCGA-D8-A1J8"  "MMEL1" "E20"   2592908
"TCGA-A2-A0EU"  "MMEL1" "E15"   2596056
"TCGA-AR-A1AJ"  "MMEL1" "E11"   2603941
"TCGA-E2-A572"  "MMEL1" "E10"   2604271
"TCGA-EW-A1J5"  "MMEL1" "E10"   2604275
"TCGA-E2-A574"  "MMEL1" "E9"    2605620
"TCGA-AC-A23H"  "MMEL1" "E5"    2609733
"TCGA-B6-A0IA"  "MMEL1" "E5"    2609757
"TCGA-AN-A0XS"  "ACTRT2"    "E1"    3021531
"TCGA-E9-A1RC"  "ACTRT2"    "E1"    3022445
"TCGA-AC-A6IW"  "ACTRT2"    "E1"    3022597
"TCGA-A2-A4S3"  "ACTRT2"    "E1"    3022696
"TCGA-A2-A0EX"  "PRDM16"    "E4"    3385231
"TCGA-B6-A0WZ"  "PRDM16"    "E5"    3396498
"TCGA-E9-A22E"  "PRDM16"    "E6"    3402898
"TCGA-BH-A8FZ"  "PRDM16"    "E9"    3411750
"TCGA-BH-A0HF"  "PRDM16"    "E9"    3412534
"TCGA-A8-A09V"  "PRDM16"    "E15"   3431074
"TCGA-5L-AAT1"  "ARHGEF16"  "E2"    3463558
"TCGA-AR-A1AI"  "ARHGEF16"  "E4"    3467276
"TCGA-E9-A1R4"  "ARHGEF16"  "E13"   3479535
"TCGA-AC-A5XS"  "MEGF6" "E37"   3490581
"TCGA-AC-A23H"  "MEGF6" "E7"    3514608
"TCGA-A2-A0SY"  "MEGF6" "E2"    3602584
"TCGA-AC-A23H"  "TPRG1L"    "E2"    3625459
"TCGA-AR-A1AS"  "WRAP73"    "E1"    3649987
"TCGA-BH-A0DX"  "TP73"  "E2"    3682353
"TCGA-A1-A0SF"  "TP73"  "E3"    3683095
"TCGA-5L-AAT1"  "TP73"  "E3"    3683125
"TCGA-A8-A095"  "TP73"  "E4"    3707673
"TCGA-BH-A0HA"  "TP73"  "E8"    3727733
"TCGA-E9-A1R5"  "CCDC27"    "E1"    3752488
"TCGA-BH-A0C0"  "CCDC27"    "E3"    3755474
"TCGA-GM-A5PV"  "CCDC27"    "E6"    3762664
"TCGA-A2-A3Y0"  "CCDC27"    "E9"    3766586
"TCGA-BH-A1F6"  "LRRC47"    "E7"    3781140
"TCGA-B6-A0WZ"  "LRRC47"    "E7"    3781267
"TCGA-BH-A0B6"  "LRRC47"    "E2"    3787022
"TCGA-AR-A2LE"  "CEP104"    "E19"   3823467
"TCGA-A2-A0EN"  "CEP104"    "E12"   3833888
"TCGA-A8-A09Z"  "CEP104"    "E11"   3835070
"TCGA-AC-A4ZE"  "DFFB"  "E7"    3883608
"TCGA-AR-A1AH"  "C1orf174"  "E4"    3890056
"TCGA-BH-A18G"  "AJAP1" "E2"    4711920
"TCGA-BH-A1F2"  "AJAP1" "E3"    4769894
"TCGA-AC-A23H"  "AJAP1" "E4"    4772372
"TCGA-C8-A12L"  "AJAP1" "E4"    4772486
"TCGA-AC-A23H"  "NPHP4" "E28"   5864419
"TCGA-BH-A1FD"  "NPHP4" "E28"   5864478
"TCGA-EW-A1IZ"  "NPHP4" "E27"   5865131
"TCGA-EW-A1J5"  "NPHP4" "E27"   5865172
"TCGA-A2-A04P"  "NPHP4" "E26"   5866378
"TCGA-D8-A1XZ"  "NPHP4" "E24"   5867849
"TCGA-4H-AAAK"  "NPHP4" "E20"   5877217
"TCGA-D8-A1JD"  "NPHP4" "E19"   5880178
"TCGA-GM-A2D9"  "NPHP4" "E17"   5890905
"TCGA-E2-A1LA"  "NPHP4" "E17"   5890987
"TCGA-D8-A1J8"  "NPHP4" "E17"   5891009
"TCGA-E2-A1B4"  "NPHP4" "E16"   5904787
"TCGA-EW-A1P3"  "NPHP4" "E13"   5907125
"TCGA-BH-A0EE"  "NPHP4" "E12"   5909177
"TCGA-A2-A0ER"  "NPHP4" "E11"   5927714
"TCGA-BH-A0HF"  "NPHP4" "E11"   5927761
"TCGA-AO-A128"  "NPHP4" "E9"    5947174
"TCGA-AC-A23H"  "NPHP4" "E4"    5969131
"TCGA-AC-A23H"  "NPHP4" "E2"    5986185
```

Comment: What determines the uniqueness of an individual?

Comment: If the "ID" column indicates the individual, then the first 4 individuals are unique and the 5th individual is the same as the 4th. Is the "count" column correct? It says `1,2,3,3,4` rather than `1,2,3,4,4`.

Comment: @Alexis The variable `ID` indicates the individual, so in the first 40 lines, the individual `TCGA-GM-A2DM` should only be counted once.

Comment: @dipetkov Yes, thank you for catching that. You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of unique individuals must be >= 30 regardless of order,
then I think this should work:

```
library(magrittr)

compute_counts <- function(ID, gene_ends) {
  ids <- as.integer(ID)

  seen_ids <- numeric()
  count <- 0L
  adjust_count <- function(id, gene_end) {
    if (!(id %in% seen_ids)) {
      seen_ids <<- sort(c(seen_ids, id)) # sort strictly not needed
      count <<- count + 1L
    }

    if (gene_end && length(seen_ids) >= 30L) {
      count <- count # copy enclosed value locally
      seen_ids <<- numeric()
      count <<- 0L
    }

    count
  }

  unlist(Map(adjust_count, ids, gene_ends))
}

out <- df %>%
  mutate(num_unique = compute_counts(ID, lastObsFlagG & lastObsFlagGE),
         group = cumsum(c(-1L, diff(num_unique)) < 0L)) %T>%
  View
```

---

This version (considering the original post) is based on dipetkov's answer,
it uses a helper function with a closure that updates the enclosed `adjustment` when the gene ends and the `count` conditions are met.

```
library(magrittr)

compute_counts <- function(ID, gene_ends) {
  rle <- rle(as.integer(ID))
  ids <- unlist(Map(rep, 1L:length(rle$values), each = rle$lengths))

  adjustment <- 0L
  adjust_count <- function(id, gene_end) {
    count <- id - adjustment

    if (gene_end && count >= 30L) {
      adjustment <<- id
    }

    count
  }

  unlist(Map(adjust_count, ids, gene_ends))
}

out <- df %>%
  mutate(count = compute_counts(ID, lastObsFlagG & lastObsFlagGE),
         group = cumsum(count == 1L)) %T>%
  View
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran the code and it seems that it only output 29 unique individual in group 1. The repeated individuals are `TCGA-GM-A2DM`, `TCGA-5L-AAT0`, `TCGA-5L-AAT1`, `TCGA-AO-A128`.

Comment: So an ID should be considered as repeated regardless of where it appears? Then run-length encoding won't be enough... That wasn't expressed in the original post though.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that in my post. I have updated the sample output and the post.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `purrr::accumulate` instead of a loop. (Actually, `accumulate2` since there are two conditions needed to decide when to switch to a new group: the individual IDs and the start of a gene indicator.)

```r
library("tidyverse")

# Helper function which expresses the switch condition
switch_group <- function(acc, individual, gene_starts) {
  if ((individual - acc) > 30 && gene_starts == TRUE) individual else acc
}

df %>%
  mutate(
    # Generate run-length type individual id's
    individual = data.table::rleid(ID),
    # Detect the start of a new gene (when its name is different from the previous gene)
    gene_starts = gene != lag(gene, default = "")) %>%
  # Detect when to switch to a new group
  mutate(switch = accumulate2(individual, gene_starts[-1], switch_group) %>% unlist()) %>%
  # The rest just restarts the counter and group id as required
  mutate(count = individual - switch + 1,
         group = data.table::rleid(switch)) %>%
  print(n = 75)
#> # A tibble: 200 x 9
#>     ID           gene     exon  mutation    id starts switch count group
#>     <fct>        <chr>    <fct>    <int> <int> <lgl>   <int> <dbl> <int>
#>   1 TCGA-AN-A046 OR4F5    E1       69767     1 TRUE        1     1     1
#>   2 TCGA-A2-A0CP SAMD11   E2      925952     2 TRUE        1     2     1
#>   3 TCGA-A8-A08H NOC2L    E5      956126     3 TRUE        1     3     1
#>   4 TCGA-GM-A2DM NOC2L    E4      956911     4 FALSE       1     4     1
#>   5 TCGA-GM-A2DM NOC2L    E4      956912     4 FALSE       1     4     1
#>   6 TCGA-D8-A1XM KLHL17   E3      961658     5 TRUE        1     5     1
#>   7 TCGA-BH-A18G KLHL17   E5      962441     6 FALSE       1     6     1
#>   8 TCGA-3C-AALI KLHL17   E8      963353     7 FALSE       1     7     1
#>   9 TCGA-AC-A62Y KLHL17   E9      964004     8 FALSE       1     8     1
#>  10 TCGA-AR-A2LE PLEKHN1  E1      966556     9 TRUE        1     9     1
#>  11 TCGA-E2-A14N PLEKHN1  E5      970728    10 FALSE       1    10     1
#>  12 TCGA-AO-A0J4 PLEKHN1  E12     973506    11 FALSE       1    11     1
#>  13 TCGA-D8-A1J9 HES4     E3      999551    12 TRUE        1    12     1
#>  14 TCGA-EW-A1PH ISG15    E2     1014276    13 TRUE        1    13     1
#>  15 TCGA-A2-A0T0 AGRN     E2     1022338    14 TRUE        1    14     1
#>  16 TCGA-GM-A2DD AGRN     E3     1035303    15 FALSE       1    15     1
#>  17 TCGA-5L-AAT1 AGRN     E4     1040690    16 FALSE       1    16     1
#>  18 TCGA-OL-A5RW AGRN     E8     1043314    17 FALSE       1    17     1
#>  19 TCGA-D8-A27M AGRN     E25    1049355    18 FALSE       1    18     1
#>  20 TCGA-AR-A1AI AGRN     E29    1050430    19 FALSE       1    19     1
#>  21 TCGA-5L-AAT0 AGRN     E36    1055374    20 FALSE       1    20     1
#>  22 TCGA-5L-AAT0 AGRN     E36    1055376    20 FALSE       1    20     1
#>  23 TCGA-C8-A8HP AGRN     E36    1055442    21 FALSE       1    21     1
#>  24 TCGA-A7-A4SD TTLL10   E13    1184971    22 TRUE        1    22     1
#>  25 TCGA-BH-A1F0 SDF4     E4     1223283    23 TRUE        1    23     1
#>  26 TCGA-AO-A128 SDF4     E4     1223330    24 FALSE       1    24     1
#>  27 TCGA-E9-A1R0 SDF4     E2     1228592    25 FALSE       1    25     1
#>  28 TCGA-A2-A04P UBE2J2   E7     1255246    26 TRUE        1    26     1
#>  29 TCGA-C8-A274 UBE2J2   E7     1255342    27 FALSE       1    27     1
#>  30 TCGA-5L-AAT1 SCNN1D   E1     1281422    28 TRUE        1    28     1
#>  31 TCGA-AO-A128 SCNN1D   E6     1287116    29 FALSE       1    29     1
#>  32 TCGA-E2-A15R SCNN1D   E7     1287596    30 FALSE       1    30     1
#>  33 TCGA-AC-A62V SCNN1D   E11    1290543    31 FALSE       1    31     1
#>  34 TCGA-BH-A18V ACAP3    E22    1294187    32 TRUE       32     1     2
#>  35 TCGA-A7-A6VX ACAP3    E6     1300640    33 FALSE      32     2     2
#>  36 TCGA-GM-A2DB ACAP3    E3     1303170    34 FALSE      32     3     2
#>  37 TCGA-EW-A1IY ACAP3    E3     1303176    35 FALSE      32     4     2
#>  38 TCGA-D8-A1XQ CPSF3L   E9     1313879    36 TRUE       32     5     2
#>  39 TCGA-5L-AAT1 CPSF3L   E9     1313888    37 FALSE      32     6     2
#>  40 TCGA-C8-A26Y CPSF3L   E7     1314919    38 FALSE      32     7     2
#>  41 TCGA-D8-A1XK CPSF3L   E2     1321057    39 FALSE      32     8     2
#>  42 TCGA-AO-A128 TAS1R3   E2     1331863    40 TRUE       32     9     2
#>  43 TCGA-A8-A07P TAS1R3   E6     1334323    41 FALSE      32    10     2
#>  44 TCGA-A7-A0DA DVL1     E14    1338066    42 TRUE       32    11     2
#>  45 TCGA-C8-A8HQ DVL1     E10    1339589    43 FALSE      32    12     2
#>  46 TCGA-BH-A18T DVL1     E8     1340130    44 FALSE      32    13     2
#>  47 TCGA-C8-A12V MXRA8    E6     1354445    45 TRUE       32    14     2
#>  48 TCGA-C8-A3M8 AURKAIP1 E2     1374747    46 TRUE       32    15     2
#>  49 TCGA-BH-A0B6 CCNL2    E11    1387308    47 TRUE       32    16     2
#>  50 TCGA-A8-A09Z CCNL2    E4     1395413    48 FALSE      32    17     2
#>  51 TCGA-AC-A23H MRPL20   E4     1402084    49 TRUE       32    18     2
#>  52 TCGA-BH-A1FU MRPL20   E4     1402116    50 FALSE      32    19     2
#>  53 TCGA-BH-A0W4 MRPL20   E4     1402194    51 FALSE      32    20     2
#>  54 TCGA-AR-A1AH MRPL20   E4     1402205    52 FALSE      32    21     2
#>  55 TCGA-A8-A06Q ANKRD65  E1     1420868    53 TRUE       32    22     2
#>  56 TCGA-AC-A8OQ ATAD3C   E1     1450566    54 TRUE       32    23     2
#>  57 TCGA-A2-A25A ATAD3C   E11    1462661    55 FALSE      32    24     2
#>  58 TCGA-AR-A5QQ ATAD3B   E7     1482563    56 TRUE       32    25     2
#>  59 TCGA-AO-A1KS ATAD3B   E12    1487900    57 FALSE      32    26     2
#>  60 TCGA-AO-A124 ATAD3B   E15    1490662    58 FALSE      32    27     2
#>  61 TCGA-A7-A56D ATAD3B   E16    1495857    59 FALSE      32    28     2
#>  62 TCGA-D8-A27N ATAD3B   E16    1495961    60 FALSE      32    29     2
#>  63 TCGA-AR-A2LH ATAD3A   E5     1518929    61 TRUE       32    30     2
#>  64 TCGA-EW-A1OY ATAD3A   E12    1525277    62 FALSE      32    31     2
#>  65 TCGA-AO-A128 ATAD3A   E16    1533987    63 FALSE      32    32     2
#>  66 TCGA-BH-A1FM SSU72    E3     1544993    64 TRUE       64     1     3
#>  67 TCGA-C8-A12Y MIB2     E4     1623874    65 TRUE       64     2     3
#>  68 TCGA-AC-A23H MIB2     E7     1625321    66 FALSE      64     3     3
#>  69 TCGA-B6-A0RV MIB2     E10    1626960    67 FALSE      64     4     3
#>  70 TCGA-E2-A1LG MIB2     E19    1629667    68 FALSE      64     5     3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: This doesn't take into account the `lastObsG==1 & lastObsGE==1` constraint.

Comment: @Alexis Thanks! You are quite right. I think I've fixed it now.